# How to insert records using select active records in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I found some questions same with this issue but i can't seem to find a right answer for my own code. so i'm going to post my problem.

my code is not working and posting errors. like "stdClass could not be converted to string" or problem regarding to array.

here's my code in model

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table1");
$query = $this->db->get();
$this->db->insert("table2", $query->result());
```

this is not working.

now when i use print_r($query) the result is this.

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #30 [result_id] => Resource id #40 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 5 [row_data] => )
```

Comment: What happens if you add `echo $query;` and `print_r($query);` between your 3rd and 4th lines?

Comment: sorry for the late reply @r3mus i've updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

If you `select('*')` it will return many rows, so it is not advisable to use `insert()`
since `insert` will only process `ONE ROW`

try using `insert_batch()`

```
$this->db->insert_batch("table2", $query->result());
//or
$this->db->insert_batch("table2", $query->result_array());
```

If you need to use `insert()` you must put a `limit(1)` to your first query.

Or you have to catch your query if it returns many rows

```
$numrows = $query->num_rows(); 
if($numrows == 1)
{
  $this->db->insert("table2", $query->row());
}elseif($numrows > 1){
  $this->db->insert_batch("table2", $query->result_array());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `$query` is coming back as an object.

Try one of the following, in place of your last line with `$query->result()`:

```
$this->db->insert("table2", $query->row());
//or
$this->db->insert("table2", $query->result_array());
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to achieve is copying data between two tables you should try this query

```
INSERT INTO to_table (field1,field2) (SELECT field1,field2 FROM from_table);
```

This is more efficient in a lot of ways. 
It produces the result in a single query. 
No data is brought into or sent from the application resulting in huge speed benefit.

Comment: he is asking about active records

Comment: I understand that @MoeedFarooqui . I am just giving him another method to get the job done, in a more efficient way.

Comment: but this way he is too close to Sql Injection